# Открытие html файла Java

Tags: java, html

Нужно, чтобы программа открывала html файл:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            URI url = new URI("D:\\3 курс\\БГУИР(лб)\\СиАТариС\\Лб5\\2\\lb5\\src\\html\\lb5.html");
            desktop.browse(url);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы именно файл был открыт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
File file = new File("D:\\3 курс\\БГУИР(лб)\\СиАТариС\\Лб5\\2\\lb5\\src\\html\\lb5.html");
URI url = file.toURI();
```

или просто:

```
URI url = new URI("file:///[file_path]");
```

где `[file_path]` – путь до файла.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File f = new File("D:\\3 курс\\БГУИР(лб)\\СиАТариС\\Лб5\\3\\lb5\\src\\main\\webapp\\index.jsp");
        desktop.browse(f.toURI());
```

Comment: Смена файла решила Вашу проблему? Если да - то как? Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.